# jQuery: pass value to field Contact Form 7

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, variables, field

I have a Contact Form 7 on a wordpress site, which has a field with id `coordinates`. In my javascript I have a variable `event.latLng`, the value of which I want to write to this field. So I add the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {$('#coordinates').val('event.latLng');});
```

However, the field now only displays 'event.latLng' instead of the value.

Any thoughts on how to change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take it out of the single quotes, you're sending in a string with the value 'event.latLng' instead of referring to the property latLng of the event object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (`'event.latLng'` should be `event.latLng`):

```
$('#coordinates').val(event.latLng);
```